# Why does testing a file after sourcing fail in Upstart?

Tags: upstart

The following Upstart script, saved as `/etc/init/upstart-test.conf` works:

```
start on filesystem
stop on on runlevel [!2345]

pre-start script
  set -x
  [ ! -f /etc/default/grub ] && { stop; exit 0; }
  . /etc/default/grub
  # [ ! -f /etc/default/grub ] && { stop; exit 0; }
end script

script
  set -x
  . /etc/default/grub
  true
end script
```

Starting it (under Ubuntu 14.04.5):

```
$ sudo initctl start upstart-test
upstart-test start/running, process 2380
```

If I uncomment the second file existence test, the job fails:

```
$ sudo initctl start upstart-test
initctl: Job failed to start
```

Why? The log shows:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/upstart/upstart-test.log 
+ [ ! -f /etc/default/grub ]
+ . /etc/default/grub
+ GRUB_DEFAULT=0
+ GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
+ GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
+ GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
+ lsb_release -i -s
+ GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=Ubuntu
+ GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
+ GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=
+ GRUB_GFXMODE=auto
+ [ ! -f /etc/default/grub ]
```

The file never goes away. The second file test line is identical; I even tried *both* copy/pasting it and typing it out manually to be sure. What's going on?

Comment: Someone [got this on Twitter](https://twitter.com/dazabani/status/782899923771502592), waiting to see if they'll post the answer here. Basically you need to end the stanza with something "truthy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve never used upstart, so this may not be the whole story.

Try adding `true` to the end of your pre-start script, just like the other `script` in your file.

When `/etc/default/grub` exists, your `[` command (which is the same as `test`) returns a non-zero exit status, which is a “falsy” value. This makes the whole command with the `&&` and the rest of the line false, so as intended, the right hand side doesn’t run, but this is the last command in the pre-start script, and upstart may see a non-zero exit status in the last command as a failure.

Comment: This seems to be it. The irony is that I added the `true` command to the `script` stanza just to fill it out. It didn't occur to me to try adding it to the `pre-start` stanza.

Comment: `exit 0` will also do it, in fact.